# TokenMismatch ONLY Certain Browsers - Laravel 5 Fresh/Production

Tags: php, session, laravel, browser

One example browser:
IE 11: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Session started at 22:46:56. Fills out form. Submits form at 22:53:18, gets `TokenMismatchException`. So only 6 minutes later.

Session Started:

`Apr 02 22:46:56 production.INFO: Session {"start":1428040016,"id":"8040cc779df0330855f8fa30483af63557aaf9c4","token":"L3nU4ehseV5w1iXy86g18FsgnVs6sAcDNjTUZ5QV","ip":"74.XX","method":"GET","url":"https://sub.domain.com/place-st","ua":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"} []`

User submits form 6 minutes later:

`Apr 02 22:53:18 production.DEBUG: REQUEST SESSION token: 8L3pba9ALBVBcrvIPM5wnTl7bP0slSIrjCAkfWzh [] []
Apr 02 22:53:18 production.DEBUG: REQUEST INPUT _token: L3nU4ehseV5w1iXy86g18FsgnVs6sAcDNjTUZ5QV [] []
Apr 02 22:53:18 production.DEBUG: REQUEST HEADER X-CSRF-TOKEN:  [] []
Apr 02 22:53:18 production.DEBUG: REQUEST HEADER X-XSRF-TOKEN:  [] []
Apr 02 22:53:18 production.DEBUG: REQUEST URL: https://sub.domain.com/requests/post [] []`

Server Vars:

`Apr 02 22:53:18 production.DEBUG: array (   'USER' => 'forge',   'HOME' => '/home/forge',   'FCGI_ROLE' => 'RESPONDER',   'APP_ENV' => 'production',   'QUERY_STRING' => '',   'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'POST',   'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',   'CONTENT_LENGTH' => '867',   'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '/home/forge/doamin.com/public/index.php',   'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/index.php',   'REQUEST_URI' => '/requests/post',   'DOCUMENT_URI' => '/index.php',   'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/home/forge/doamin.com/public',   'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.1',   'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => 'CGI/1.1',   'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => 'nginx/1.6.2',   'REMOTE_ADDR' => '74.XX',   'REMOTE_PORT' => '56563',   'SERVER_ADDR' => '104.XX',   'SERVER_PORT' => '443',   'SERVER_NAME' => 'doamin.com',   'HTTPS' => 'on',   'REDIRECT_STATUS' => '200',   'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*',   'HTTP_REFERER' => 'https://sub.domain.com/place-st',   'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => 'en-US',   'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',   'HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',   'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => 'gzip, deflate',   'HTTP_HOST' => 'sub.domain.com',   'HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH' => '867',   'HTTP_CONNECTION' => 'Keep-Alive',   'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL' => 'no-cache',   'PHP_SELF' => '/index.php',   'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => 1428040398.7879851,   'REQUEST_TIME' => 1428040398, ) [] []`

Session/Cookie

`Apr 02 22:53:18 production.DEBUG: REQUEST PATH: requests/post [] []
Apr 02 22:53:18 production.DEBUG: COOKIE: array ( ) [] []
Apr 02 22:53:18 production.DEBUG: SESSION: array (   '_token' => '8L3pba9ALBVBcrvIPM5wnTl7bP0slSIrjCAkfWzh', ) [] []`

HTTP Request:

`Apr 02 22:53:18 production.DEBUG: POST /requests/post HTTP/1.1 Accept:          text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */* Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language: en-US Cache-Control:   no-cache Connection:      Keep-Alive Content-Length:  867 Content-Type:    application/x-www-form-urlencoded Host:            sub.domain.com Referer:         https://sub.domain.com/place-st User-Agent:      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko  _token=L3nU4ehseV5w1iXy86g18FsgnVs6sAcDNjTUZ5QV&var=value&var2=value2&etc... [] []`

Comment: this can an important bug, maybe file an issue on gitthub laravel/laravel

Comment: @jhauraw were you able to check my answer ?

Comment: Does this happen if you submit the form in 1min? Or only 6mins? What about 5mins etc?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange it's not us submitting the form, but a multitude of users on different browsers. Yes, it happens at various intervals from session start to form submit. There is no pattern in the time, except that all the instances are less than the session lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds *alot* like this known issue with Laravel: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8172

The cause is not yet known, and it has been going on for a while. There are a lot of smart people looking into it - but the apparent randomness of the issue is making it difficult to debug.

I suggest you contribute your information to that ticket and keep an eye there for further information. Specifically we need as much information about your server config and app config as possible - so we can try to replicate the issue. So far the exact method to replicate is not known, making a fix difficult.

Comment: Yes, the randomness is beyond frustrating. We are getting 2-3 per day on a busy system. I'll post a scenario on the issue ticket asap.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is not related to browsers. I believe that there are some people who wait too long and the session expires. After submitting form with expired session the TokenMismatchException happens.

For debugging you can save to log when each of the session is created to see if it was supposed to be expired and you can also play with session lifetime in session.php

Comment: I've updated my question with a better example. Not expired session.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a long shot but the source of the problem could be compatibility mode of IE and different sessions of those modes using.

Can you try it with adding this line on top of the get and post pages:

```
header("X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge");
```

Comment: We already have the X-UA meta tag on every get page, per usual Twitter Bootstrap UI standard. Are you saying we should add a PHP header on POST request?

In <head>, already:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Also, Android 4.4.* with Chrome 41 is having the same issue, so IE is not the only one.

Comment: @jhauraw could you please share your post and get views and controllers ?

Comment: @jhauraw there is a chance posts are handling before any html output.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think you're asking is output is being sent before headers?